# Why do these 2 images appear with a different shade of red in Firefox, if in Photoshop they look the same and both have the sRGB profile embedded?

Tags: firefox, photoshop, user-experience, color-profile, srgb

[image: more_yellow]

[image: more_red]

These 2 images both have the same PNG extension, both have the sRGB color profile embedded in them, and the background is for both #f14505. However in Firefox they are shown in 2 different shades of red.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Needed to remove gamma correction with pngcrush

```
pngcrush -rem gAMA input.png output.png
```

Comment: In the images above, only one of them has an embedded profile.

Comment: how did you check?

Comment: You can open the image in most any photo editing application to inspect the embedded profile. On MacOS, just use PREVIEW and command I for inspector.

Comment: Can you tell how to view it in Photoshop? I don't use Mac. The only thing I did to get the darker look like the other one is to execute the gamma correction command.

Comment: To find the most complete answer, Google: Photoshop check color profile